# How can I run GEB from a Grails service?

Tags: grails, geb

I'm trying to run GEB from a web-service on Grails since I need to extract data from a page and use it on my aplication.
The server is suposed to scrap the info and then return it into a view.

If I run it from the grails console it works fine but when I run it from the service it doesn't work

here's the code

```
package com.bamboozled
import geb.Browser
import grails.transaction.Transactional


@Transactional
class ScraperService {

Data scrapIt(String nombreCiclo, String numeroSolicitud) {
    //Variable con los datos a retornar
    def d = new Data()

    //Inicia el bot
    Browser.drive {

        go "http://some.page/page.php"

        $("form").ciclo = nombreCiclo
        $("form").nosol = numeroSolicitud
        $("form").find("input", name: "BOTONACEPTAR").click()

        def a = getAvailableWindows()

        def data = [" "," "," "," "," "]

        withWindow(a[1]) {
            data[0] = $("td")[5].text()
            data[1] = $("td")[6].text()
            data[2] = $("td")[7].text()
            data[3] = $("td")[8].text()
            data[4] = $("td")[9].text()
        }


        d.numeroSolicitud = data[0]
        d.avance = data[1]
        d.seEncuentraEn = data[2]
        d.numeroCheque = data[3]
        d.cheque = data[4]


        }
        return d
    }
}
```

Here is the controller where I call it

```
package com.bamboozled

class DataController {
    static scaffold = true

    def ScraperService

    def index() { }

    def form() {
    }

    def consulta(){
      def p = Ciclo.findAll()
      [solicitudes : p]
    }

    def resultados() {
        def d = ScraperService.scrapIt(params.nombreCiclo, params.numeroSolicitud)
        [res : d]
    }

}
```

When I run it it gives this error

```
URI
/bamboozled/data/resultados

Class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Message
geb/Browser

Around line 200 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
197:            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cacheOperations)) {
198:                log.debug("No cacheable annotation found for {}:{} {}",
199:                        new Object[] { request.getMethod(),     request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });
200:                chain.doFilter(request, response);
201:                return;
202:            }
203:
Around line 63 of AbstractFilter.java
60:     try {
61:         // NO_FILTER set for RequestDispatcher forwards to avoid double gzipping
62:         if (filterNotDisabled(request)) {
63:             doFilter(request, response, chain);
64:         }
65:         else {
66:             chain.doFilter(req, res);
Around line 17 of grails-app/services/com/bamboozled/ScraperService.groovy
14:        def d = new Data()
15:
16:        //Inicia el bot
17:        Browser.drive {
18:
19:            go "http://http://some.page/page.php"
20:
Around line 20 of grails-app/controllers/com/bamboozled/DataController.groovy
17:    }
18:
19:    def resultados() {
20:        def d = ScraperService.scrapIt(params.nombreCiclo, params.numeroSolicitud)

21:        [res : d]
22:    }
23:
Trace
    Line | Method
->>  200 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
->>  200 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->>  200 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: geb/Browser
->>   17 | $tt__scrapIt in ScraperService.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     20 | resultados in DataController.groovy
|    200 | doFilter  in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Any idea of how can I make it run?

Comment: Is Geb on your classpath? it's usually on your testCompile only, make sure it's in compile scope as well so it's available for your app

Comment: See https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/october-2017-scraping-with-geb/.